# Cannot Get JsonConvert.DeserializeObject with oData to Work

Tags: json, rest, odata

I a class that looks like so:

```
public class AccountAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int accountNumber { get; set; }
    public int rowNumber { get; set; }

    public string civicaddress { get; set; }

    public AccountAddress()
    {
        //Default constructor
    }
}
```

There is a rest API that returns a List of AccountAddress as oData that looks like this to a variable "result":

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:52139/odata/$metadata#WEB_V_CIVIC_ADDRESS/Values.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress","value":[
    {
      "@odata.type":"#Values.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress","accountNumber":123456,"rowNumber":0,"civicaddress":"123 FAKE EAST DRIVE"
    },{
      "@odata.type":"#Values.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress","accountNumber":123457,"rowNumber":0,"civicaddress":"123 FAKE WEST DRIVE"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to use:

```
var addressAccountLookup =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountAddress>>(result);
```

I get an error

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ATPublicTAX.Regina.ca.Values.Classes.Entities.AccountAddress]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the entire object to your deserialization method. You need to pass only the array, which is what it's asking you to do.

```
JArray array = (JArray) result["value"];
var addressAccountLookup =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountAddress>>(array);
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I got to work is create a class:

```
private class oDataResponse<T>
    {
        public List<T> Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
var oDataRespone = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<oDataResponse<AccountAddress>>(result);
```